# Making a walking effect with kivy

Tags: python, pygame, kivy

This my first time on stack overflow and am hoping I would get help.

I am new to kivy and would love to build a game like temple run with kivy, I have an idea how, but my problem is making my avatar to have that running effect. I was thinking that I could use a gif image, but it did not work.

Please help on how to animate my avatar.

Comment: Post your code so we can get an idea about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Further to @Paul's comment, you may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a game where I had many .png files which I wanted to animate into an explosion. I put the .png files into a .zip file and did the following:

```
explosion = Explosion(
    size_hint=(None, None),
    source='explosion.zip', 
    anim_delay=0,
    allow_stretch=True,
    keep_ratio=False)
```

where `Explosion` was this:

```
class Explosion(Image):
    pass
```

While all those various keyword arguments are not necessarily relevant to you, take note of the `source`, and maybe also, the `anim_delay` args. For me, making it zero made it so there was a smooth animation, but it could be different with a gif.

**From the Image docs:**

> anim_delay
>
> Delay the animation if the image is sequenced (like an animated gif).
>   If anim_delay is set to -1, the animation will be stopped.
>
> anim_delay is a NumericProperty and defaults to 0.25 (4 FPS).

It's been a while since I made the game, but here is a snippet from earlier in the code:

```
def __init__(self, **kw):
    super(myGame, self).__init__(**kw)

    # pre-load zipped pngs using keep_data to avoid delays later
    load_zipped_png_files = Image(
        source      = 'explosion.zip', 
        anim_delay    = 0,
        allow_stretch = True, 
        keep_ratio    = False,
        keep_data     = True)
```

I believe that this have the effect of keeping the zipped .png files in memory thereby avoiding delays in loading them later on. This may not actually be having the desired effect, I can't remember to be honest, however, I do remember thinking that it did! I recommend testing it out for yourself if you go this route. And please let me know if it works out.